# Cancel AlarmReceiver from service class

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have class for call myService with alaram Manager. From mainActivity this is my code to set alarm manager.

```
Intent downloader = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
                downloader.putExtra("limit", limit.getSelectedItem().toString());
                downloader.putExtra("delay",perMin.getSelectedItem().toString());
                downloader.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);    `pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, downloader,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
int delay = Integer.parseInt(perMin.getSelectedItem().toString());
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,10 * 1000, delay * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

and here my alarm receiver class
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent update = new Intent(context, IntervalService.class);
    Log.i(tag, "Call service from Alaram Receiver");
    context.startService(update);
}}
```

I know when i want to cancel alarm manager from main activity easily call alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent) but i want to cancel alarm manager to complete my service task and after that set again like as above.

Comment: Just use another broadcast but with an `Intent` extra indicating the alarm should be cancelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modified your code,

```
public void setAlarmManager(boolean cancel){

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,downloader,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
int delay = Integer.parseInt(perMin.getSelectedItem().toString());
if(!cancel)
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,10 * 1000, delay * 1000, pendingIntent);
else
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

}
```

call this function when needed,

to Start: setAlarmManager(false);

to Cancel: setAlarmManager(true); //Call this function in Service

Try, this may work. Thanks.